# Mistake in jquery function

Tags: jquery, timeout

I have some jquery timeout function, but I think I made some syntax mistakes, can someone correct me where I did it wrong

I want to scroll page after 5 second, but if user click on button that I don't want to scroll, here is what I have for now, it is OK when user click but I don't know how to prevent another scroll? Here is my example code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var clickScroll = 0;

    $('.jumper').click(function () {
        clickScroll = clickScroll + 1;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".section-one-home").offset().top - 98
        }, 2000);


    });

    if (clickScroll == 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".section-one-home").offset().top - 500 }, 2000);
        }, 5000);
    }

});
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: you did mistake in spelling in first line

var clikcScroll = 0; change it to var clickScroll = 0;

Comment: Thats was here error :( I have edited but still not working

Comment: clickScroll = clickScroll + 1; in this replace 1 to 100 so you know whether script is running or not?

Comment: I have modified the question, but still does not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that using `clearTimeout` to cancel the function in the `setTimeout` like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var clickScroll;

    clickScroll = setTimeout(function () {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".section-one-home").offset().top - 500 }, 2000);
        }, 5000);

    $('.jumper').click(function () {
        clearTimeout(clickScroll);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".section-one-home").offset().top - 98
        }, 2000);
    });

});
```